# TypeError [ClientMissingIntents] | Discord Bot Coding | node.js / discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Whenever I try to run my bot's code using `node .`, the following error message appears:

```
TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (D:\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:489:13)
    at new Client (D:\Neuer Ordner\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Neuer Ordner\index.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:84:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'ClientMissingIntents'
```

My Code is:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token =
  "";
const prefix = "t/";
bot.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("BOT WENT ONLINE");
});

bot.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith("prefix")) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {
    message.channel.send("PONG");
  }
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {
    message.channel.send("WRONG COMMANDS!");
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```

I'm starting out with discord bot development, so I'm not sure what I can do to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

## Why the error?

**Your code does not specify the intents that it needs to run when logging in, hence why it fails.** As stated in the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents):

> Gateway Intents were introduced by Discord so bot developers can choose which events their bot receives based on which data it needs to function. Intents are named groups of pre-defined WebSocket events, which the discord.js client will receive. If you omit DirectMessageTyping, for example, you will no longer receive typing events from direct messages. If you do not specify intents, discord.js will throw an error.

## How to fix this

Firstly, **check your discord.js version using `npm list`**. The code you have written is for an older version of discord.js (v12.x), however based on the logs you've provided, the discord.js version you're using seems to be newer (v13.x or v14.x) and won't work with it.

If your discord.js version is 12.x or below, then run `npm remove discord.js` then `npm install discord.js` to install the latest version of discord.js.

I've included answers for versions 13.x and 14.x below:

## The solution

##### Here is the baseline code you need for your bot to operate (source: [discordjs.guide](https://v13.discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file))

Notice how at line 2 your bot's token isn't being stored in a variable, but rather we're now trying to access it from a `config.json` file. It's generally a somewhat safer way of storing your token.

Read the guide from [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#using-config-json) and follow the steps on configuring a `config.json` file to store your token a bit more safely, or preferrably install a package like `dotenv` (`npm install dotenv`) to handle your bot's secret keys instead.

## If you are using discord.js v14.x

Inside of your `index.js` file:

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
// We use 'c' for the event parameter to keep it separate from the already defined 'client'
client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});

// Log in to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

## If you are using discord.js v13.x

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

## Both for discord.js v13.x and v14.x

Inside your `config.json` file:

```json
{
    "token": "your-token-goes-here"
}
```

## What about commands?

You may have noticed that the snippet above doesn't include any code for interacting with the bot. Read below, this is very important:

**If your bot is in under 100 servers and you do not plan on growing it, you can create text commands with a prefix, but it generally isn't the recommended way of interacting with bots anymore**. Because of data privacy restrictions, discord will prevent your bot from joining more than 100 servers if you are using the message content intent and haven't had it specifically approved by discord. Read more about this on [discord's article](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ#:%7E:text=MESSAGE%20CONTENT%20IS%20BECOMING%20A,in%20100%20or%20more%20servers.).

If you still want to read message content for text commands or moderation features, then add `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` and `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages` inside of the `intents: []` array like so:

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages] });
```

...and listen for messages using the `messageCreate` event (place this below the `client.login(token)` line):

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    // Logs the message being sent by a user
    console.log(message);

    // add your prefix code here...
}
```

Read more on the guide on how to use slash commands (the newer, more intuitive and powerful way of interacting with Discord bots) [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html#creating-slash-commands).

Please take some time to read the documentation or guide via the links above, or even watch a recent tutorial video if you'd like a more interactive way of coding your new discord bot.

Best of luck on your bot coding adventures! I know it's a lot to take in, but give it some time and patience, and you'll figure it out in no time.